# Opening an InfoWindow from a clickable Polygon Googlemaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In researching the answer I've consulted the API documentation and example, many similar queries on stackflow and some Youtube examples but none are exactly what I'm looking to create and I can't fathom where I'm going wrong.

In this instance we wish the infowindow to appear by clicking within the defined border of the polygon, not by selecting a marker.  I understand Googlemaps lets you do this as long as you give your infowindow a LatLng position.

What I can't understand is why the infowindow is not opening...

Please could you review code and let me know if you can spot anything obvious I'm missing.  (Hope it's clear in the code notes but I'm looking to create many different are polygons across the same map)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TBC</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
* element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }


#myDIV {
width: 100%;
padding: 50px 0;
text-align: center;
background-color: lightblue;
margin-top:20px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"style="width:800px;height:1200px;"></div>

 <script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {{
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 17.247253, lng: 79.1},
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });





//BEGINNING AREA CODE 1
// Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
    var hyderabadCoords = [

{lat:17.3876090549752,lng:78.5106470783611},
{lat:17.4637690550461,lng:78.5161870783663},
{lat:17.4391290550232,lng:78.4386270782939},
{lat:17.3876090549752,lng:78.5106470783611},


         ];

// Construct the polygon.            
  var hyderabadBorder = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: hyderabadCoords,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.0
    });
    hyderabadBorder.setMap(map);

//Content of infobox

var hyderLatLng = {lat: 17.39, lng: 78.50};     
var contentString = "TBC"
var hyderinfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,  
  position:hyderLatLng
    });

 // Add a listener for the click event.
  hyderabadBorder.addListener('click', showArrays);

hyderinfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
}
//END AREA CODE 1
//BEGINNING AREA CODE 2...(Repeat 1 with new area details)
//END ALL AREA CODES


/** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
 function showArrays(event) {
var vertices = this.getPath();
}


}   
        </script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?        key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

1. you are overwriting the InfoBox that has the content in it with one that is empty:

```
hyderinfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
```

2. You are never calling `hyderinfowindow.open(map);`

```
function showArrays(event) {
  hyderinfowindow.open(map);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5dwoftcw/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: 17.247253,
        lng: 79.1
      },
      zoom: 9,
      mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });

    // Construct the polygon.            
    var hyderabadBorder = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: hyderabadCoords,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.0
    });
    hyderabadBorder.setMap(map);

    //Content of infobox
    var hyderLatLng = {
      lat: 17.39,
      lng: 78.50
    };
    var contentString = "TBC"
    var hyderinfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      position: hyderLatLng
    });

    // Add a listener for the click event.
    hyderabadBorder.addListener('click', showArrays);
  }
  //END AREA CODE 1
  //BEGINNING AREA CODE 2...(Repeat 1 with new area details)
  //END ALL AREA CODES

  /** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
  function showArrays(event) {
    hyderinfowindow.open(map);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
//BEGINNING AREA CODE 1
// Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
var hyderabadCoords = [

  {
    lat: 17.3876090549752,
    lng: 78.5106470783611
  }, {
    lat: 17.4637690550461,
    lng: 78.5161870783663
  }, {
    lat: 17.4391290550232,
    lng: 78.4386270782939
  }, {
    lat: 17.3876090549752,
    lng: 78.5106470783611
  },
];
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
* element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```